# tvOS : didUpdateFocusInContext prevents number of taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I have several custom buttons in my view and made them a custom focus animation with `didUpdateFocusInContext` ,and  I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view that when user taps twice a method will run ! but the problem is when `didUpdateFocusInContext` prevents to  double tap action until the `focused context` reaches its end (it means riches to the last button) then method will fire when there is no focusable context !!! how can prevent such thing ? Here is my code :

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator: (UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
  
    
    //Setup focausing for main buttons
    for (UIButton *mainButton in _nextPrevButton){
        
        if (context.nextFocusedView == mainButton) {
            
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.40 initialSpringVelocity:.60 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
                
                context.nextFocusedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
                context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
                context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
                context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
                context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
                context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
                
            } completion:nil];
            
        } else {
            
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.40 initialSpringVelocity:.60 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
                context.previouslyFocusedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                context.previouslyFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }
    
    

if (context.nextFocusedView == _button1Focused) {   [self buttonFocused:context];   }   else if   (context.previouslyFocusedView == _button1Focused) {    [self buttonNotFocused:context];    }
if (context.nextFocusedView == _button2Focused) {   [self buttonFocused:context];   }   else if   (context.previouslyFocusedView == _button2Focused) {    [self buttonNotFocused:context];    }
if (context.nextFocusedView == _button3Focused) {   [self buttonFocused:context];   }   else if   (context.previouslyFocusedView == _button3Focused) {    [self buttonNotFocused:context];    }
 
    
}
```

## Tapping methods :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     UITapGestureRecognizer *rightTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightTap:)];
        [rightTap setAllowedPressTypes:@[@(UIPressTypeRightArrow)]];
        [rightTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightTap];
}

- (void)handleRightTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    
  //or put the code here ! 
    
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right Arrow");
        
    }
}
```

I tried other states :

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // handling code
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ");
}


if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    // handling code
    NSLog(@" UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ");
}

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
{
    // handling code
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized");
}
```

but no success !